# Getting parent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**JS**

```
   <script>           
        $('.btn').click(function(e){
           target = e.target;
           parent = target.parentNode.parentNode;
           console.log(parent);
        });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="user-icon"></div>
        <h4 class="job-type">Painter</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"><strong>Job Description:</strong><span> Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</span></p>
        <p class="card-text"><strong>Payment:</strong><span> $40</span></p>
        <p class="card-text"><strong>Location:</strong><span> 25 Apple str.</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm info" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Info
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                Apply Now
            </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the card element and its children but sometimes whenever i click the button i get the buttons parent instead which is

```
<div class="card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm info" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Info
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                Apply Now
            </a>
    </div>
```

and sometimes i get the card element
can someone please explain to me why that is [console image][1]

[image]

Comment: inside your click function just do `$(this).closest(".card")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you probably sometimes click on a `glyphicon` and that becomes your `target` and sometimes you click on text and than it behaves as you expect.

You could use for expample `$(this).closest(".card")` instead of `target.parentNode.parentNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) this is going to be the actual element you clicked on, in your case you could have clicked on the `span` or the `a`.

So when you use something like `e.target.parentNode` you are getting the parent of that element. Either `<div class="card-body">` for span or `<div class="card">` for `a`. That is why you can get differing results.

Alternatively if you had used [e.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) it would always reference the element that you attached the listener to, in your case the `<a class="btn">`

If you are trying to get a specific ancestor element then use the DOM api's [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method or jQuery's [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method. Either will get the closest ancestor element that matches the passed selector

```
//either will get you the <div class="card"> element
let parent = e.target.closest('.card');
let parent = $(e.target).closest('.card');
```